# changing returning variadic function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, variadic-functions

I'm trying to pass some variadic parameters through pointer but I haven't quite get it.
The parser isn't working, but this is not my problem.
I'm using a subset of C, but don't worry about syntax or lexic.

It is supposed to be used like:

```
void functionX(void){
  action[100]="GO_PLAY(12345,23)";
  char id[10];
  char offset[10];
  ParseCommand("GO_PLAY",action,2,&id,&offset);
  // after this id should be "12345" and offset should be "23"
}

bool ParseCommand(char *command, char * buffer,int count, ...){
  bool returnvalue=FALSE;
  int command_len=O_strlen(command);
  int buffer_len=O_strlen(buffer);
  int j=command_len+1;
  va_list ap;
  int parameter=0;
  char *parsed_text;
  va_start(ap, count);         /* Initialize the argument list. */
  while(parameter<count) {
    while(buffer[j]!=','&& buffer[j]!=')') //search argument
      j++;
    if(j<buffer_len) { // argument found
      calloc(MODULE,parsed_text,j-(command_len+1),sizeof(char));
      substr(command_len+1,j,buffer,parsed_text,buffer_len);
      *va_arg(ap,char*)=parsed_text; // why isnt this working?
      parameter++;
      j++; // to continue to search
    }
  }
  leave:
  va_end (ap);
  return returnvalue;
}
```

Comment: What does your code do, and how does that differ from what you were hoping for?

Comment: And: what are those `calloc` and `substr` calls? There's a `calloc` in the C standard library, but it only takes two arguments.

Comment: I reformatted your code a little. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: calloc is a macro  #define calloc(module,var,nItems,itemSize) do { ... }

Comment: substr is a function to get a substring char *substr(size_t start, size_t stop, const char *src, char *dst, size_t size)

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure `parsed_text` isn't just a random uninitialized pointer, which is what it is right now. Otherwise `substr` is writing to some random place in memory. Or, probably better: `substr(command_len+1,j, buffer, va_arg(ap,char*), buffer_len)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `*va_arg(ap,char*)=parsed_text`,

try : `sprintf(va_arg(ap, char*), "%s", parsed_text);`

Answer (score 0):

`va_arg(ap,char*)` returns a value of type `char*`. That is, it's a pointer to `char`. But you're trying to store a `char*` value at the place it points to. I think you actually want to copy the characters you've extracted from the command there, with `strcpy` or `memcpy` or something of the kind.

Incidentally, if you do that then your parser -- just like the `scanf` functions if used incautiously -- will be vulnerable to buffer overflows if it's asked to parse something containing arguments that are too long for the variable they're being stored in. But that's a separate issue, and it may or may not be a serious problem depending on the rest of your code.

(Perhaps instead you were intending to copy the (pointer) value of `parsed_text` rather than copying the characters. But then you have another problem: `id` and `offset` aren't pointer variables so you couldn't do that even if you wanted to.)

Other issues:

I don't see any memory being allocated for `parsed_text`, but it's hard to tell without seeing the definition of `substr`. Is it a function or a macro? What exactly is it supposed to do? Actually, if `substr` is allocating memory, you have a different problem, because nothing is freeing it again.

If your input command has the wrong syntax, your `while` loop can run off the end of the string, looping for ever until it tries to access some memory it's not allowed to. This will happen, e.g., if you call `ParseCommand("GO_PLAY","GO_PLAY(broken",2,&id,&offset)`.

Comment: thank you for the very complete comments. I'm not handling any errors write now. I'm supposing the person who is writing the command does it properly ... (:|) thank you for the help!!